rust rocket form validate email regexp
trying to make work this piece of rust code to test rocket web framework and i want to test custom validation for a form input email address with regexp to be more specific than just testing the presence of @ char. The code below not compile so any help appreciate please o/
the code below not compile :
use rocket::form::{FromForm};
use regex::Regex;

#[derive(FromForm)]
pub struct Person {
    #[field(validate=len(1..))]
    pub(crate) first_name: String,
    #[field(validate=len(1..))]
    pub(crate) last_name: String,
    #[field(validate=len(1..))]
    pub(crate) email_address: String,
}

#[derive(FromForm)]
pub struct Email<'r> {
    #[field(validate = contains('@').or_else(msg!("email must contain '@'"))
        .and_then(|addressl| {
            let re = Regex::new(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$").unwrap();
            if re.is_match(address) {
                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err(msg!("invalid email format"))
            }
        })
    )]
    pub(crate) r#address: &'r str,
}

and below error output when cargo run :
$ cargo run
   Compiling rocketapp v0.1.0 (/home/user/Downloads/rocketapp)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/models.rs:22:21
    |
22  |                 Err(msg!("invalid email format"))
    |                 --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                 |   |
    |                 |   the found closure
    |                 |   expected `Errors<'_>`, found closure
    |                 arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `Errors<'_>`
              found closure `{closure@/home/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rocket-0.5.1/src/form/validate.rs:151:23: 151:26}`
help: the type constructed contains `{closure@/home/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rocket-0.5.1/src/form/validate.rs:151:23: 151:26}` due to the type of the argument passed
   --> src/models.rs:22:17
    |
22  |                 Err(msg!("invalid email format"))
    |                 ^^^^----------------------------^
    |                     |
    |                     this argument influences the type of `Err`
note: tuple variant defined here
   --> /home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/result.rs:536:5
    |
536 |     Err(#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")] E),
    |     ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `rocketapp` (bin "rocketapp") due to 1 previous error


Have you tried using a fully qualified syntax for the msg! macro?

That does the trick with good imports :
use rocket::form::{FromForm, Errors, Error};
Err(Errors::from(Error::validation("invalid email format")))
Many Thank's

That was just a hunch. Glad it worked.
